# Send out multiple emails from Webpage Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an webpage with asp.net C#.

I want people to log on and enter in quote requests. then the quote request is emailed to all the relevant people to quote (could be 100+ people).

Obviously I can not have the user sit and wait for the 100+ people to be emailed as the webpage will freeze.

I have thought about implementing a backend program on the server. perhapes that checks for a text file or something and when that text file is there. searches the database for any un-emailed quotes. and emails to the relevant people. then marks record as emailed.

But there must be a better way? IS there a que system or something designed to do things like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
```

in a loop to queue your email sending. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx for info.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like Microsoft message queue, and then have a task that sweeps the queue periodically.

I'd get the website to push to the queue, as have the queue set-up as persistent so if the box crashes, restarts etc. nothing is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just send it. If it freezes more than 0.1 seconds or so you need better hardware and confiuguration.

- Have the SMTP class write to a FOLDER On disc, have the locally installed SMTP service use this as pickup directory. Then youre page is done the moment the file is written. Stnadard .NET classes support this setup via a simple configuration setting. Most people never bother to read the documentation, though.

Noo network invovlved, just 100 file generation or so. Or even 10 files with 10 bcc recipients each. Finished.

Generating 10 small files should be fat. if your discs overload get a small SSD ;) They cost near nothing.

All the rest is a lot of programming work and introduces more to watch into your system.

Comment: This is the approach that I would use too. However I would just generate and save the email files into the Queue folder of the SMTP server.

Comment: Possibly, but it adds a little problem if the SMTP server is down. I use a windows service to copy the emails there... and inject a tracking code. If an email comes back as spam, I can find out  where it originated from and whether it came really from a website ;)

Comment: Yes. Note that I dont track anything else. I inject 2 GUIDs that also go into a database and cross reference the user that generated the file, which is the work account of the application pool and MOST of the time uniquely identifies a website, at least a set of sites (customer, multi site application). I also track hashes of target and origin address and the length - not the address. BUt I can get a warning if you start sending emails for the same address suddenly by hundreds ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the two, although it wouldn't be the approach I'd use.

But using your example, you could create a static listener interface to your backend (server) application, and instead of putting a file and check periodically, you could ping your backend operation to start the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Generating 1 email with 100 people in the "To" or "CC" fields should **not** cause the page to freeze up. Have you actually observed this behavior? If so, check your SMTP configuration, as something sounds amiss.

However, the solution I've seen put into good use, is to have a SQL database that holds all pending messages to be sent out, then have SQL Server run a job every ten minutes to run through that pending table and do the emailing (as opposed to emailing straight from the .NET app).

Comment: Adding everyone to 'To' or 'CC' will cause everyone to see everyone's email address.  That's a privacy issue.  You could use 'BCC' with your approach, but it's not exactly a scalable solution.

Comment: Its only a privacy issue if the recipients are not linked together, say, in a single company. For internal apps in large organizations, there's no issue. That's the world I'm in, so I guess it what I always assume is the default unless otherwise stated. The Question implies the recipients are under some umbrella organization, although its not crystal clear.